# Can Rails be deployed locally? without using git

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have made an app with the use of Git and Heroku.
I'm curious if i can deploy Ruby on Rails locally without using Git.

Comment: deploy locally == Run rails server locally? If yes, run `rails server` and load up http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't going to deploy to Heroku, you don't technically need Git at all.  Just delete the .git folder.  Given that Git is a great tool however,  doing this is a bad idea.

You can deploy a Rails app locally, and the typical way to do this is with Apache and Passenger ( I'm assuming you are using a flavor of linux, OSX may have a host running already ).

It has been a while since I had done this, but this page seems to have the right idea:

https://nathanhoad.net/how-to-ruby-on-rails-ubuntu-apache-with-passenger

Answer (score 0):

Rails s or rails server (in terminal) and you have localhost:3000. This is your local rails program and is incredibly convienent for development. Of course you need to be in the directory of your program to deploy it on localhost